# Spark Serialization: How Tungsten and Kryo work together?

Tags: apache-spark, serialization, kryo

I was reading about Spark optimization and I wasn't clear how **Tungsten** and **serialization** like Kryo work together.

Some notes from the sources I was reading that made me thought of this question:

- "Tungsten’s representation is substantially smaller than objects serialized using Java or even Kryo serializers."
  [source-hortonworks](https://community.hortonworks.com/articles/72502/what-is-tungsten-for-apache-spark.html)
- "With code generation, we can increase the throughput of serialization, and in turn increase shuffle network throughput." 
  [source-databricks](https://databricks.com/blog/2015/04/28/project-tungsten-bringing-spark-closer-to-bare-metal.html)

Answer (score 2):

They don't, excluding some border-cases like `Encoders.kryo`.

Tungsten uses it's own binary storage format and corresponding serde tools (`Encoders`). That's why it can be faster and more memory efficient in standard operation mode.

Comment: Thanks. So how Tungsten is used when "By default, Spark serializes objects using Java’s ObjectOutputStream framework"? @user9963938